# SUM of all values on a custom field

Tags: roll-up-summary

I have a custom object and have a custom currency field called salary.

I want to find the sum of this salary field using a formula field.

Is this possible?
I am not using master-detail and roll-us.

Thanks

Comment: DLRS is your friend here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible as described. You need to either

1. Alter your data model, using a master-detail field to make Roll-Up Summary Fields available.
2. Use a third-party application like [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).
3. Write Apex triggers to manually perform the rollups.

You won't be able to achieve this with formula fields or with purely declarative automation (unless you use a third-party product).